# Объединить масив в строку

Tags: c++

Есть код, который сортирует слова по количеству гласных. Проблема в том, что нужно вывести это как строку, то-есть сформировать с них строку, но я немного не понимаю как.
сам код:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <vcl.h>
#include <iostream.h>
 
int count_vowels(char * word)
{
    int count = 0; 
    char vowels[] = "AEIOUYaeiouy";
    
    for(char * p2 = word; *p2; ++p2)
        for(char * p1 = vowels; *p1; ++p1)
            if(*p1 == *p2)
                ++count;
 
    return count;
}
 
 
int main(void)
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    string s;
    char strings[10][32], str[32];
    FILE *f;
    int count = 0, i, j;
    if((f = fopen ("file.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    while (feof(f) == 0 || count > 10)
    {    
        fscanf (f, "%s", str);
        strcpy(strings[count++], str);
    }
    fclose(f);
    

    for(i = 0; i < count - 1; ++i)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < count - 1 - i; ++j)    
        {
            if(count_vowels(strings[j + 1]) > count_vowels(strings[j]))
            {
                strcpy(str, strings[j]);
                strcpy(strings[j], strings[j + 1]);
                strcpy(strings[j + 1], str);
            }
        }
    }


    for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", strings[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Я писала через условие там, то выдает ошибку.

```
    s+=str+" ";
    if(strings[i]=='.')
    s+=".";
    printf(" ",s);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Напишите вот так ` s+=string(str)+string(" ");`

Comment: А если вам разрешено пользоваться `std::string` зачем вы используете массивы с-строк? Используйте сразу string - `std::string strings[10], str` и все операции делайте со `string`.

Comment: @DmitryK, спасибо помогло. По заданию нужно использовать массив, так что использую его. А строки использую для объединения в строку.

Comment: Ну тогда по заданию и итоговую c-строку наверное надо использовать. Создать буфер `char buf[1000]` и в него копировать все строки последовательно.

Comment: @DmitryK, та просто учитель странный у нас. Ерунду зачастую говорит и всё. Но, спасибо за подсказку, буду знать на будущее. :)

Comment: Насчет сортировки. Вы в сортировке выполняете копирование строк. Этого можно избежать. Создайте массив указателей на строки и меняйте местами указатели. `char* ptr[10]; ptr[0] = strings[0];`

Comment: Ну и последнее c-строки вот так сравнивать нельзя `if( strings[i] == '.' )`. Если бы это была `std::string s`, то тогда было бы можно `if( s == '.' )`.